# Backbone collection fetch not processing params

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to show todos by "project" (an attribute) in this kind of format:

```
-----------------------------------------
Project: Project1
Task            Due         Priority    Delegated
task1           9/18 @500p  A       Roy
task2           9/18 @500p  A       Roy
task3           9/18 @500p  A       Roy
-----------------------------------------
Project: Project2 
Task            Due         Priority    Delegated
task1           9/18 @500p  A       Maggie
task2           9/18 @500p  A       Maggie
task3           9/18 @500p  A       Maggie
-----------------------------------------
```

So that I could have access to the collection/models on the client side for sorting within each project, I wanted to fetch with params "completed":false, then use underscores _.groupBy, but the fetch is ignoring the params and returning all models in the collection.

```
var todosCol = new TodosCol();
todosCol.fetch( {
    // processData: true, // no effect
    // traditional: true, // no effect
    // data:    $.param( { "completed": false } ) // no effect
    data: { "completed": false }
} );
var groups = _.groupBy( todosCol.models, function( model ){
    return model.get( "project" );
} );
```

My collection:

```
define( function( require ){

    var $               = require( "jquery" ),
    Backbone            = require( "backbone" ),
    _               = require( "underscore" ),
    bootstrap           = require( "bootstrap" ),
    LocalStorage            = require( "LocalStorage" ),

    TodoModel           = require( "home/HomeContentTodoModel" );

    return Backbone.Collection.extend( {
        model:          TodoModel,
        localStorage:       new Store( "todos" )
    } );

} );
```

Insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the backbone.localstorage library? If so, i would hazard a guess that parameters are useless in this situation, b/c they're meant to be handled by your server code. Query parameters have no use case with LocalStorage. Just a guess.

Comment: @EricGuan is right, you might find this code helpful: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/examples/backbone_require/js/collections/todos.js#L19